# Run extension command on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the *Sorting HTML and Jade attributes* extension which offers the command **attrsSorter.execute**.  I would like to setup my workspace settings.json so that "editor.codeActionsOnSave" section runs this every time before saving, then formatting / linting so that we get the sorted benefit.

Have looked all over the place and cannot figure out how to simply execute this each time save is performed.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5):

I needed to format CSS files on save by executing the [PostCSS Sorting extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-postcss-sorting) and I found this tutorial: [Automatic CSS sorting in VS Code](https://www.ashvinmotye.com/blog/automatic-css-sorting/)

According to it you have to install the extension:  **ryuta46.multi-command** and then modify the keybindings.json file. (F1 + Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON))

Mine looks like this:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
          "sequence": ["postcssSorting.execute", "workbench.action.files.save"]
        },
        "when": "editorLangId == css"
      }
]
```

I hope it helps someone! :)

Comment: damn simple & working beautifully, thanks mate <3

Answer (score 4):

I just lost way too many hours of my life figuring out how to run the command `test-explorer.run-all` defined by [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter). If you substitute `editor.codeActionsOnSave` for `test-explorer.run-all` everywhere below I think that should work.

What I've hacked together is to first of all install the [Trigger Task on Save extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.triggertaskonsave)
which, instead of bash commands as per the other answer, runs VS code tasks on save.

As per [the VS code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks)
you can then define a custom task to wrap the command. For me, this looks like

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "mocha-explorer",
      "command": "${command:test-explorer.run-all}",
    }
  ]
}
```

Here `mocha-explorer` is my own arbitrary label for this.
Finally, configure the `settings.json` file to run your task on save by its label, which for me looks like:

```
    "triggerTaskOnSave.tasks": {
        "mocha-explorer": ["*.js"]
    }
```

I'm a total newb to all this VS code config but I hope that helps someone.

A related useful answer that may be helpful for more complex tasks: [Is there a way to run a command with VS Code tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48510288/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-command-with-vs-code-tasks)

Comment: In my case I used this to execute auto formatting all markdown tables on save, which works - however I do run into the issue of the file constantly being in a state of 'unsaved' because the task is executed after the save command is run - not sure how to tackle this yet.

Answer (score -1):

[You can use this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave)

Run On Save for Visual Studio Code

This extension allows configuring commands that get run whenever a file is saved in vscode.

Comment: I am aware of this extension and it works for issuing command line commands on save.  However, it does NOT allow for you to execute the "commands" provided by other extensions and if you look at the issues on the github repo for the extension you reference it has been asked for a couple of times and not implemented.